# How to avoid previous printed line's shadow, while overwriting various statement using \r in perl?

Tags: perl

I am developing one console application using perl script. In that I am printing status of the process like "25 % Completed", "33.33 % completed" etc... In that I am using \r for printing the statement in oneline. But, while execution the previous printed statement shadow also exist, which gives confusion. How to avoid that shadow of the previous printed statement. Example code has been written below.

```
use strict;
$|=1;

my $length=7;
my $progress_limit=100/$length;
 my $progress;
for(my $i=1;$i<=$length;$i++){
 $progress=$progress_limit*$i;
 print "Process completion status\: ".$progress." % Completed \r";

}
```

Thanks ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a fixed length string. [sprintf](http://p3rl.org/sprintf) formatting is a great way to achieve that.

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use IO::Handle qw(); STDOUT->autoflush(1);

for my $i (1..7) {
    printf "Status: %3d%% completed\r", $i * 100/7;
    sleep 1;
}
```

Comment: @daxim : Any reason in particular for not using `$|++`?

Comment: Personal style decision to avoid action-at-a-distance. It does not matter in this example, but [I do it for consistency](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9465036#comment-11976679). As a teacher, I must foresee that this code lands someplace where someone messes with select, and then the defensively written code wins. It's too easy to make mistakes with $| that I relegate it to one-liners only. Other minor benefit: words are easier to look up in the documentation than punctuation variables.

Comment: Exact same action at a distance exists for `STDOUT->autoflush(1);`. If you didn't want action at a distance, you'd use `STDOUT->flush()` or `$|=$|;` after the `print`.