# Convert Old Unix Date to Perl and compare

Tags: perl, shell, date, time

**Requirement** - I have file name called "Rajesh.1202242219". Numbers are nothing but a date "`date '+%y''%m''%d''%H''%M'`" format.
Now I am trying to write a perl script to extract the numbers from file name and compare with current system date and time and based on output of this comparison, print some value using perl.

**Approach:**

**Extract the Digit from File name:**

```
if ($file =~ /Rajesh.(\d+).*/) {
print $1;
        }
```

**Convert this time into readable time in perl**

```
my $sec  =  0;  # Not Feeded
my $min  =  19;
my $hour =  22;
my $day  =  24;
my $mon  = 02   - 1;
my $year = 2012 - 1900;
my $wday = 0;   # Not Feeded
my $yday = 0;   # Not Feeded

my $unixtime = mktime ($sec, $min, $hour, $day, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday);
print "$unixtime\n";
my $readable_time = localtime($unixtime);
print "$readable_time\n";
```

**find Current time and compare...**

```
my $CurrentTime = time();
my $Todaydate = localtime($startTime);
```

But the problem here is, I am not getting solution of how to extract 2 digit from `$1` and assign to `$sec`, `$min`, etc. Any help?

Also, if you have good approach for this problem statement, Please share with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) might be a better fit.

```
if ( my ( $num ) = $file =~ /Rajesh.(\d+).*/ ) {
    my ( $year, $mon, $day, $hour, $min ) = unpack( 'A2 A2 A2 A2 A2', $num ); 
    my $ts = POSIX::mktime( 0, $min, $hour, $day, $mon - 1, $year + 100 );
    ...
}
```

Comment: He's using two digit years though.

Comment: @flesk, yup, saw that and fixed it.

Comment: Once i do , $ts - $CurrentTime, this returns -$CurrentTime value which is not correct. Could you please suggestion how you are comparing between this and current dates?

Answer (score 7):

I like to use time objects to simplify the logic. I use [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/module/Time::Piece) here because it is simple and light weight (and part of the core). DateTime can be another choice.

```
use Time::Piece;
my ( $datetime ) = $file =~ /(\d+)/;
my $t1 = Time::Piece->strptime( $datetime, '%y%m%d%H%M' );
my $t2 = localtime(); # equivalent to Time::Piece->new

# you can do date comparisons on the object
if ($t1 < $t2) {
    # do something
    print "[$t1] < [$t2]\n";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Might as well teach [DateTime](http://p3rl.org/DateTime)[::Format::Strptime](http://p3rl.org/DateTime::Format::Strptime) to make the comparison much simpler:

```
use DateTime qw();
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw();

if (
    DateTime::Format::Strptime
        ->new(pattern => '%y%m%d%H%M')
        ->parse_datetime('Rajesh.1202242219')
    < DateTime->now
) {
    say 'filename timestamp is earlier than now';
} else {
    say 'filename timestamp is later than now';
};
```

Comment: DateTime is a three-edged sword.

Comment: +1, but why do you `use DateTime` explicitly when `DateTime::Format::Strptime` already does that and use both modules with empty import lists?

Comment: flesk: Both pertain to my choice of good style: I will not rely on hidden effects. Whenever I make use of a module, I take care to load it explicitely first. I can't construct an example where it would matter with this code, and it's exceedingly unlikely that DT::F::S stops loading DT some day anyway, but I like being consistent. – See about [empty import list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6547453#comment-7714112). ––

Comment: @daxim So by using an empty list, you stop the module from automatically importing variable and function names?

Comment: Something like that, yes. Again, doesn't matter for the specific example, but [consistency++](http://ddg.gg/?q=timtoady+bicarbonate).

Comment: You don't rely on other modules to load modules for you. When you do, you'll eventually be burned by it. Load any module you use explicitly.

Comment: @flesk, I would have done the same. If one uses DateTime directly, one loads DateTime. Simple. No need to analyse whether it's safe to omit the loading. Doesn't cause one to pause when one realises the module is uses yet never loaded.

Comment: @TLP, It causes `use` to not call `import`, so it prevents per-invocation actions, including default exports. It doesn't prevent load-time actions, though.

Comment: @flesk, It's not a matter of consistency. Are you suggesting that one digs into DateTime's code to check for export lists? What about past and future versions? If one explicitly states imports (like I do), then one needs to specify it for DateTime too.

Comment: @ikegami: No, I'm not suggesting that. I just didn't notice that he's using `DateTime->now` and thought he was loading `DateTime` only because `DateTime::Format::Strptime` uses it.

Comment: @flesk, I thought you were asking why daxim used empty import lists. I guess "and use both modules with empty import lists" should be "and use DateTime with empty import list".

Comment: @ikegami:  Those were really two independent questions, but my wording could have been better. The first was due to skimming the answer and not realizing he used DateTime directly in the answer. The second was about the magic of empty import lists that was resolved in the exchange between TLP and daxim further up.

Comment: @flesk, That's how I understood it, and I responded to each separately. You misattributed my comment to the second as a comment on the first. The reason to use empty imports is to be sure nothing is getting imported. It's no practical to check the source code (past, present and future) to make sure the module doesn't export anything.

Comment: @ikegami: Ah, I see that now. Thanks for the thorough replies anyway. I didn't know there existed such a way to prevent default exports. I see it's documented in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html but I haven't thought of it before.

Answer (score 3):

```
my ($year, $month, $day, $hour, $min) = $file =~ /(\d{2})/g;

if ($min) {
    $year += 100; # Assuming 2012 and not 1912
    $month--;
    # Do stuff
}
```

Comment: $min can be "00" so maybe it would be easier to read if you said: "if ( defined $min ){" .. Guess it works like it is now  ass well, since "00" is true ??

Comment: If `defined $min` is more readable is a matter of taste, but for the specified file name format `$min` will never be defined and false, since "00" is true, unlike "0".

Answer (score 2):

Using a module that parses dates might be nice. This code will parse the date and return a [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) object. Refer to the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) to see the many ways to manipulate this object.

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $date = "1202242219";
my $dt = get_obj($date);

sub get_obj {
    my $date = shift;
    my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
        pattern     => '%y%m%d%H%M'
    );
    return $strp->parse_datetime($date);
}
```